# Kafka Connect MongoDB Sink vs Mongo Client

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to build an app that reads from Kafka and writes the data to MongoDB.
Most of the times, the data will be written as is, but there will be cases where some processing on the data will be needed.

I wonder what to do -

Use Kafka Connect MongoDB Sink **or** use our "old and familiar" approach of building an app with Kafka consumer and write the data to Mongo using MongoDB client (runs on K8s).

What are the adventages\ disadvantages of using Kafka connect? in terms of monitoring, scaling, debugging and pre-processing of the data?

Thanks